# Start terminal on Raspberry Pi using SSH

Tags: python, ssh, terminal, raspberry-pi

My question regards SSH on Raspberry Pi.

I am able to successfully ssh on to the Pi using the command:

```
sudo ssh pi@<ipaddress>
```

and then entering the password.

Let's say I have a Python script file on the Pi that I execute over SSH. Let's say the script reads:

```
    import time
    while True:
        print('Hello')
        time.sleep(1)
```

This will print 'Hello' every second whilst the terminal/command prompt window is still open (that is, the computer I am using to access the Pi is running and the SSH session remains open). If I close the connection, then the code will stop being executed on the Pi.

Is there a way I can use SSH to keep the code running on the Pi even when I close the window running SSH on the computer I am using to access the Pi? As in the Pi will keep printing 'Hello' even after I shut down my computer. Maybe by entering a command to open a terminal window on the Pi itself and running the script in that terminal window?

Is there a way this can be done?
Thanks

Comment: How about a cronjob, that is set to run a python script every minute ?

Comment: But surely when I shut down the terminal window on the computer being used to access the pi, the cronjob would end?

Comment: if pi is still working I guess no. When you close your access to an operation system it shouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options I can think of:

- create a `cron` job. This method is usually used to execute scripts/programs repeatedly. The job is triggered by the `cron` program, so it doesn't matter whether or not you are connected to the Pi, as long as it runs. You just have to connect once and setup the job (typically using `crontab -e`).
- use `screen` (on [Wikipedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694890/start-terminal-on-raspberry-pi-using-ssh)) or `tmux` (on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux)). Those are called terminal multiplexers, and allow you to keep shells (and thus any script/program) running although you aren't connected. Note that, in this case, you will have to manually start your script each time, so this solution is well-suited to scripts that run for a long time but are not started too often.

Comment: Thanks! I have used to screen solution which works well. I feel like this should be a standard tool that comes with the R Pi - who wants to have their main computer on all day running the session